# Record user click on links in email

Tags: email, outlook, gmail

I am working on a problem statement. I want to record if users have open a link given in the mail they receive.

Things work as expected for most of the cases. But the records get bad in some cases. What my research found is, when a mail is sent to users there is some link checkers on the mail servers that open the links and perform check for malicious activities. In some cases, I am able to get if the request was made by person or link checker by seeing the header of the request. Some link checkers (Yahoo mail for example) send user-type object in header. But some link checkers don't sent any information and the click is recorded on our end.

Wanted to know if they is a solution the problem or other way to record if link in the mail is clicked by user.

Answer (score 0):

Email client applications don't provide anything for checking whether a user has clicked on the link or not. The best what you could do is to redirect links to your web server where you could track when the link was clicked and then redirect to the target URL.

Answer (score 0):

There are no events in the Outlook or Word Object Model (Outlook uses Word editor both in the editor in the reading pane).

The best you can do is patch one the Windows API functions (CreateProcess?) that Outlook uses to launch a browser. You can use a library like [Detours](https://github.com/citronneur/detours.net) for that.